# How to cache an instrumented class with an instance forwarder?

Tags: caching, java-8, byte-buddy, vavr

The use case is to implement a dirty field tracker. For this I have an interface:

```
public interface Dirtyable {

    String ID = "dirty";

    Set<String> getDirty();

    static <T> T wrap(final T delegate) {
        return DirtyableInterceptor.wrap(delegate, ReflectionUtils::getPropertyName);
    }

    static <T> T wrap(final T delegate, final Function<Method, String> resolver) {
        return DirtyableInterceptor.wrap(delegate, resolver);
    }

}
```

In the interceptor class the wrapping method is:

```
static <T> T wrap(final T delegate, final Function<Method, String> resolver) {
    requireNonNull(delegate, "Delegate must be non-null");
    requireNonNull(resolver, "Resolver must be non-null");

    final Try<Class<T>> delegateClassTry = Try.of(() -> getClassForType(delegate.getClass()));

    return delegateClassTry.flatMapTry(delegateClass ->
            dirtyableFor(delegate, delegateClass, resolver))
            .mapTry(Class::newInstance)
            .getOrElseThrow(t -> new IllegalStateException(
                    "Could not wrap dirtyable for " + delegate.getClass(), t));
}
```

The method `dirtyableFor` defines a ByteBuddy which forwards to a specific instance at each call. However, instrumenting at every invocation is a bit expensive so it caches the instrumented subclass from the given instance's class. For this I use the `resilience4j` library (a.k.a. `javaslang-circuitbreaker`).

```
private static <T> Try<Class<? extends T>> dirtyableFor(final T delegate,
                                                        final Class<T> clazz,
                                                        final Function<Method, String> resolver) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Try<Class<? extends T>> r = Try.of(() -> ofCheckedSupplier(() ->
            new ByteBuddy().subclass(clazz)
                    .defineField(Dirtyable.ID, Set.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
                    .method(nameMatches("getDirty"))
                    .intercept(reference(new HashSet<>()))
                    .implement(Dirtyable.class)
                    .method(not(isDeclaredBy(Object.class))
                            .and(not(isAbstract()))
                            .and(isPublic()))
                    .intercept(withDefaultConfiguration()
                            .withBinders(Pipe.Binder.install(Function.class))
                            .to(new DirtyableInterceptor(delegate, resolver)))
                    .make().load(clazz.getClassLoader())
                    .getLoaded())
            .withCache(getCache())
            .decorate()
            .apply(clazz));

    System.out.println("Instrumentation time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

    return r;
}

private static <T> Cache<Class<? super T>, Class<T>> getCache() {

    final CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
    final CacheManager manager = provider.getCacheManager();

    final javax.cache.Cache<Class<? super T>, Class<T>> cache =
            manager.getCache(Dirtyable.ID);

    final Cache<Class<? super T>, Class<T>> dirtyCache = Cache.of(cache);
    dirtyCache.getEventStream().map(Object::toString).subscribe(logger::debug);

    return dirtyCache;
}
```

From the logs, the intrumentation time drops from 70-100ms for a cache miss to 0-2ms for a cache hit.

For completeness here is the interceptor method:

```
@RuntimeType
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public Object intercept(final @Origin Method method, final @This Dirtyable dirtyable,
                        final @Pipe Function<Object, Object> pipe) throws Throwable {

    if (ReflectionUtils.isSetter(method)) {
        final String property = resolver.apply(method);
        dirtyable.getDirty().add(property);

        logger.debug("Intercepted setter [{}], resolved property " +
                "[{}] flagged as dirty.", method, property);
    }

    return pipe.apply(this.delegate);
}
```

This solution works well, except that the `DirtyableInterceptor` is always the same for cache hits, so the delegate instance is also the same.

Is it possible to bind a forwarder to a supplier of an instance so that intercepted methods would forward to it? How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a stateless interceptor by making your `intercept` method `static`. To access the object's state, define two fields on your subclass which you access using the `@FieldValue` annotations in your now static interceptor. Instead of using the `FixedValue::reference` instrumentation, you would also need to use the `FieldAccessor` implementation to read the value. You also need to define the fields using the `defineField` builder method.

You can set these fields either by:

1. Adding setter methods in your `Dirtyable` interface and intercepting them using the `FieldAccessor` implementation.
2. Defining an explicit constructor to which you supply the values. This also allows you to define the fields to be `final`. To implement the constructor, you first need to invoke a super constructor and then call the `FieldAccessor` several times to set the fields.

Doing so, you have created a fully stateless class that you can reuse but one that you need to initialze. Byte Buddy already offers a built-in `TypeCache` for easy reuse.

Comment: Did you set the fields? Maybe you apply the interceptor on the setters?

Comment: After many unsuccessful attempts I went through solution 1. It's more verbose and fields cannot be final, but it works! Here is my solution 2 attempt:
  `.defineConstructor()
  .withParameters(delegateClass, Function.class)
  .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(delegateClass.getConstructor())
  .andThen(ofField(DELEGATE_FIELD).setsArgumentAt(0)
.andThen(ofField(RESOLVER_FIELD).setsArgumentAt(1))))`

Comment: For solution 1 I have added the matcher condition `isDeclaredBy(delegateClass)` to avoid intercepting the added setters for delegate and resolver. Also after `Class::newInstance` I call the setters by reflection to avoid adding them to the `Dirtyable` interface. I want to keep it clean :)